# How to canonicalize XML in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, canonicalization

Is there a JavaScript library for XML canonicalization with support for [Exclusive XML Canonicalization](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xml-exc-c14n-20020718/#sec-Use)?

If there is no library for that, how can I canonicalize XML in a Node.js library with minimal requirements (no Ruby or Java)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there are no XML libraries for Node.js that do C14n yet, I looked at this a while back and the easiest route seemed to be to add the functionality to the libxml library:
https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs

Answer (score 0):

You an use [xml-crypto](https://github.com/yaronn/xml-crypto) to sign XML in javascript / NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like now there's a dedicated npm package for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-c14n