# How perform Inclusive Canonicalization of XML in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml, canonicalization

Is there any short, dependencies free, lightweight code for such canonicalization? Also, I tried to find open source implementations but found only irrelevant ones.

I saw [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9308169/2104560) but asker looking for exclusive canonicalization and answerer recommended not pure JS library.

Also, there are nice libraries like deoxxa and xml-crypto but both of them doesn't support **inclusive** canonicalization. Proof: [deoxxa](https://github.com/deoxxa/xml-c14n#included-canonicalisation-algorithms), [xml-crypto](https://github.com/yaronn/xml-crypto#supported-algorithms).

Does anybody know good JS library for inclusive canonicalization, i.e, where

`canAlgo!= ...xml-exc-c14n...` but `canAlgo==...REC-xml-c14n-...`

Comment: Recommendation questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow (which you probably know, being a member for two years and all...)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, but other question by link looks almost similar to mine (after my edits).

Comment: That question was asked in early 2012, more than three years ago. If it were posted today, it would be closed.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I edited my question and now I'm not only asking for recommendations but asking for short code sample. Actually, there are few simple rules but applying them in JS may be very painful and requires a lot of boilerplate code. May be somebody wrote such code in the past and may share it with me. For example, Jquery parse xml and further jquery methods usage may help me to aplly some rules but I'm looking for simple code for all rules. May be I have to use 3-4 libraries and somebody know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [modified](http://git.nitec.kz/baurzhansahariev/ESign/blob/webcrypto/content/src/main/webapp/xml/xml-c14n.js) deoxxa's project(hosted on own gitlab server).

I was too lazy to rename exclusive to inclusive but my .js file performs inclusive.